# Argument of type * is not assignable to parameter of type *

Tags: typescript

Argument of type '({ ItemName, ItemRarityStandard, count }: { ItemName: any; ItemRarityStandard: any; count: any; }) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => string'.
Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ ItemName: any; ItemRarityStandard: any; count: any; }'.

and

Property 'count' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

```
                const capitalise = (str: string) => str.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, (c) => c.toUpperCase());

                const counts = data.Items
                  .toSorted((a: { ItemID: number; }, b: { ItemID: number; }) => b.ItemID - a.ItemID) // sort by ID highest to lowest
                  .reduce((acc: { [x: string]: { count: number, ItemName: String, ItemRarityStandard: String }; }, { ItemID, ItemName, ItemRarityStandard }: any) => {
                    acc[ItemID] ??= {
                        ItemName,
                        ItemRarityStandard,
                        count: 0,
                    };
                    acc[ItemID].count++;
                    return acc;
                }, {});
                
                const str = Object.values(counts)
                .map(({ ItemName, ItemRarityStandard, count }) => `${count}x ${capitalise(ItemName)} **${ItemRarityStandard}**`)
                .join("\n");
```

I was expecting a list of items in a specific order.

Comment: does `data.Items.toSorted` returns array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.values(counts)` produces the type `unknown[]` so when you call `.map` on this array, the type of each item is `unknown`. You cannot destructure the unknown type, you need to assert that the `unknown` type is your object type instead.

```
const str = (Object.values(counts) as { count: number, ItemName: string, ItemRarityStandard: string }[])
    .map(({ ItemName, ItemRarityStandard, count }) => `${count}x ${capitalise(ItemName)} **${ItemRarityStandard}**`)
    .join("\n");
```

Also use `string` not `String` in your typings.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is use `Map`, it is safer than `Object.entries` because you control what entries are inside of it:

```
const capitalise = (str: string) => str.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, (c) => c.toUpperCase());

                const counts = ([] as { ItemID: string, ItemName: string, ItemRarityStandard: string }[])
                  .reduce((acc: Map<string, { count: number, ItemName: string, ItemRarityStandard: string }>, { ItemID, ItemName, ItemRarityStandard }) => {
                    const old = acc.get(ItemID);
                    // do we have element?
                    if (old === undefined) {
                        acc.set(ItemID, {
                        ItemName,
                        ItemRarityStandard,
                        count: 0,
                    });
                    } else {
                        acc.set(ItemID, { ...old, count: old.count + 1});
                    }
                    return acc;
                }, new Map());
                
                const str = [...counts.values()]
                .map(({ ItemName, ItemRarityStandard, count }) => `${count}x ${capitalise(ItemName)} **${ItemRarityStandard}**`)
                .join("\n");
```